# Return value in Javascript function (Sum of number divided by 3)

Tags: javascript, arrays, return-value

I my task is to call this function and return value of sum of all number in array that can be divided by 3. The problem is that I do not know how to make return value of the function in JS. Can You please help?
Thank You

```
function sumNumbersBy3(...numberArray) {
        for(let i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++)
        {
            if (numberArray[i]%3 == 0)
                return
        }
    }
    console.log("sumNumbersBy3", sumNumbersBy3(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) === 18);
```

Comment: i'd recommend you starting with basics of javascript first

Comment: Unclear what exactly you want to know. Returning a value from a function is as simple as putting that value behind the `return` keyword. For example: `function test() { return 42; }` will return `42` when called.

Comment: I can see where was the problem now... I was only confused with "{}" brackets. I defined the "sum" variable then typed "sum += numberArray[i];" inside the "if" condition but then I put return sum also inside the "if" condition inside the brackets... That confused me... always these {brackets}. Thank You for help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a variable to sum numbers which satisfies condition `numberArray[i] % 3 == 0`:

```
function sumNumbersBy3(numberArray) {
  let sum = 0
  for(let i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++)
  {
      if (numberArray[i] % 3 == 0)
          sum += numberArray[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

In addition, you can use `reduce` method:

```
const result = arr.reduce((a, c, i) => {
  (c % 3 == 0) ? a += c : 0;
  return a;
}, 0);
```

An example:

```js
function sumNumbersBy3(numberArray) {
  let sum = 0
  for(let i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++)
  {
      if (numberArray[i] % 3 == 0)
          sum += numberArray[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log("sumNumbersBy3: ", sumNumbersBy3([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const result = arr.reduce((a, c, i) => {
    (c % 3 == 0) ? a += c : 0;
    return a;
}, 0);
console .log(`Using reduce method: ${result}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sumNumbersBy3(...numberArray) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
        if (numberArray[i] % 3 == 0)
            sum += numberArray[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
console.log("sumNumbersBy3", sumNumbersBy3(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
```